# `Since as a` vs `Ever since I was a`

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense, non-native-english

Example:

> *Since as a* little kid, I had passion about ...

Is this acceptable to say as opposed to:

> Ever since I was a little kid, ...

or

> Since I was a little kid, ...

Is It possible to write this without '*I* '?

Because the context ( [CV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae) ) is about me and I think writing `I was` is a little redundant. Plus, the graphic design of the paper requires less used space.

Or is this completely wrong and has a fundamental grammatical error?

Comment: You can say *since childhood*. You can not say "*since as a child*".

Comment: @DanBron Thanks! It could've taken me days to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Since as a* little kid, I had passion about ...

This is not an acceptable alternative to the phrasings below it.  It might be a valid usage if by "since" you mean "because" and what follows describes the *consequence* of your childhood passion.

> *Ever since I was a little kid, ...*

*or*

> *Since I was a little kid, ...*

*Is It possible to write this without 'I'?*

Assuming you leave the rest of the words, **no**.

*Because the context is about me and I think writing `I was` is a little redundant. Plus, the graphic design of the paper requires less used space.*

Dan Bron's suggestion "Since childhood" might be a good choice, or even more concisely you could put an adjective (e.g. "longtime," "lifetime" or "childhood") on "passion" and make "passion" the subject of its clause ("lifetime passion for...")